# How to display variable value from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is my scenario. I have this jsp form:

welcome.jsp

```
 <div class="ajax-wrap" style="display: block; height:100%;">
    <p class="overlay_title">
    <%-- <span><%=request.getAttribute("mes_add_pageTitle")%></span> --%>
    <% String userlabel=(String)request.getAttribute("mes_add_pageTitle");%>
    </p>
 </div>
```

and I have this is my WelcomeServlet.java:

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
    String UsernameLabel="passing value";
    request.setAttribute("mes_add_pageTitle",UsernameLabel); //Setting USernameLabel to mes_add_pageTitle

    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/welcome.jsp");
    rd.forward(request,response);  //forwarded to welcome.jsp   
}
```

My problem is why I get null value in jsp. It should display `Username Label` but it doesn't work.. what is my mistake please help. Note: `Username Label` is a label so I don't need get or post. Thanks

Comment: The variables is stored in the servlet and I want to display them in jsp

Comment: my welcome file is index.jsp

Comment: I did. But I still get null value. . What's wrong with my code?

Comment: <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

Comment: That is my welcome file in web.xml

Comment: yes I have a index.jsp. The contents of it is header and my footer

Comment: sorry it's jsp . Am I coding in the right way? The only thing I want is to display the variable value that is stored in servlet to jsp.

Comment: its display a `null` word.

Comment: I did it. . The name of the servlet is WelcomeServlet. But it display null

Comment: Try creating a new project, with just one servlet and jsp for simplicity

Comment: okay I will try to create new project. Hope it will works

Answer (score 3):

index.jsp:

```
 <form action=Servlet1">
 <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit1">
  </form>
```

In Servlet,

Lets consider, 
Servlet1.java

```
if(request.getParameter("submit1")!=null)
{
String UsernameLabel="passing value";
request.setAttribute("mes_add_pageTitle",UsernameLabel); //Setting UsernameLabel to mes_add_pageTitle

RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/welcome.jsp");
rd.forward(request,response);  //forwarded to welcome.jsp
```

welcome.jsp:

```
<% String userlabel=(String)request.getAttribute("mes_add_pageTitle"); %>

Value is: <%=userlabel%>
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: Where will I put the codes. In `doGet` function or `doGet` ?

Comment: I tried inside this, 

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

Comment: May I see your whole jsp file? I get null value still please

Comment: can you post your servlet and jsp page..the codings again here?

Comment: did you try to print it..try to print using

<%=userlabel%>

or <% out.println(userlabel); %>

Comment: Still the results I get is null. . What Am I doing wrong.  :'-(

Comment: input.jsp:
<form action="servlet1">
name: <input type=text name="sname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit1">

----servlet1:-----
processRequest:
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
if(request.getParameter("submit1")!=null)
{
   String sname="request.getParameter("sname");
   session.setAttribute("sname",sname);
//forward using Request Dispatcher to Welcome.jsp

-----welcome.jsp:------

<% String sname=(String)session.getAttribute("sname"); %>

<% out.println(sname); %>

-----------------------------

try this code and let me know...

Comment: That will work because there is a submit button. I just only one is to access my variable value from servlet to jsp. All the variables I have in jsp is used for labels. For example I have a variable like this `private String username= "Usename label"`. And I want to display `Username label` in my jsp. That's it.

Comment: use session to store the variable in Servlet and get it in JSP and try printing it...

Comment: How to do that. Can you give me a sample. I am stock doing that for 6 hours with no good results :-(

Comment: processRequest: 
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
String UsernameLabel="passing value";
session.setAttribute("mes_add_pageTitle",UsernameLabel);
//use RequestDispatcher

---------------------------------------

welcome.jsp:
<% String usernameLabel=(String)session.getAttribute("mes_add_pageTitle"); %> 
<% out.println(usernameLabel); %>

Comment: I will give it a try :-)

Comment: I think I almost wanted to give up. . I still get a null result. :-( I copy the codes but null result.

Comment: hmm when I run my project. I right click it->run as server. How will I know if I run first the servlet?

Comment: I do not see a run file. Just Run on a Server. And after I runned it. I get a blank page

Comment: There should be a Run option, when you right click your Servlet.java file..and click Run..it should run (make sure your servlet is defined in web.xml)

Comment: Just only I see it `Run on server`. and I also defined the servlet in my web.xml. I am using eclipse kepler by the way

Comment: In netbeans there is an option to run the servlet..since your variable has been declared in servlet and then passed to JSP..its better to run servlet first and the variable is passed to JSP..or create a sample JSP only with submit button and pass it to Servlet..

Comment: When I click the submit button the url directs here : `http://localhost:8080/Test/WelcomeServlet%22?submit1=submit`. The when I remove `%22?submit1=submit` I get a blank page.

Comment: WelcomeServlet is the name

Comment: so you mentioned <form action="WelcomeServlet"> right?

Comment: Yes I did. . But I get a blank page. . What should I do next?

Comment: i am not able to get where the error occur's in your code..i cant solve without checking it..actually the above code should work..it passes to Servlet and passes to JSP again..

Comment: Did u use the `processRequest` function? If so, where did you call it?

Comment: we dont need to call functions in Servlet..when you create a servlet..there will be 3 methods..process request, doGet and do Post..we wrote code in process request..it will go for code..and with Request Dispatcher..it goes to JSP

Comment: I do not know what happen to my codes. I try to put a 'system.out.println' below the `processrequest` function and I run it but I didn't see the print so I think maybe after I submit it. It doesnt execute the `processRequest` function

Comment: System.out.println prints only in Console..it wont work in Servlets

Comment: ah okay. . hmm maybe I need to search more about this on how to retrieve the variables from servlets to jsp. :-(. Thank u very much to ur help

Answer (score 0):

In JSP, mes_add_pageTitle  variable needs to be declared outside of sriptlet(<% %>) tag.

Declare it like <%! String mes_add_pageTitle = null   %>

Comment: I still get null value.

Answer (score 0):

While dispatching use

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/welcome.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

and while retrieving in jsp use

```
<%=request.getAttribute("mes_add_pageTitle")%>
```

Comment: I still get null value. :-(